# Why is hydrogen gas so highly reactive?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Why is Hydrogen so reactive? What makes it combustible?

Comment: Please note that the [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) on this site requires you 
to show some personal effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hydrogen is not particularly reactive.

For example, just mixing hydrogen and oxygen gas will not cause a reaction at room temperature, but many metal elements oxidize at least on the surface in air.

The most reactive elements in my opinion are fluorine in the non-metals, and the alkali metals like sodium and potassium.

It is combustible because oxygen wants electrons and takes them from hydrogen to form water.

Comment: Hmm, Dave, looking at the reactivity from the general point, shouldn't Cs be more reactive than Na?

Comment: yes, francium and cesium are the most electropositive, I was just lumping the alkali metals together, and givng sodium and potassium as examples of alkali metals